# Axios giving unauthenticated error on post request while the get request works with the same user token tried logging out but it didn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, axios, get

Axios giving unauthenticated error on post request while the get request works with the same user token tried logging out and in again but it's not working I think I am writing something wrong if anybody could help it would be very appriciable.

error:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/api/v1/projects 401 (Unauthorized)

Error: Request failed with status code 401
    at e.exports (isAxiosError.js:10:1)
    at e.exports (isAxiosError.js:10:1)
    at l.onreadystatechange (isAxiosError.js:10:1)
```

```
const userToken =
  "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiI2MzVmOGQzMzUzMTY3MzIyODBkNTJlNDQiLCJuYW1lIjoiUmFtIiwiaWF0IjoxNjY3ODQ3Nzg4LCJleHAiOjE2NzA0Mzk3ODh9.dHAdhvFphiN08hZKHyCEW5a5s3GHtaUtyOFlAnNkgSA"

const showProject = async () => {
  loadingDOM.getElementsByClassName.visiblity = "visible"
  try {
    const {
      data: { projects },
    } = await axios.get("api/v1/projects", {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + userToken,
      },
    })
    if (projects.length < 1) {
      projectDOM.innerHTML =
        '<h5 class="empty-list">No projects in your list</h5>'
      loadingDOM.style.visibility = "hidden"
      return
    }
    const allProjects = projects
      .map((project) => {
        const {
          _id: projectId,
          projectName,
          discription,
        } = project
        return `<div class="single-project">
                <h5><span><i class="far fa-check-circle"></i></span>${projectName}</h5>
                <h5><span><i class="far fa-check-circle"></i></span>${discription}</h5>`
      }).join("")
    projectDOM.innerHTML = allProjects
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    projectDOM.innerHTML =
      '<h5 class="empty-list">There was an error, please try later....</h5>'
  }
}

showProject()

// create project

formDOM.addEventListener("submit", async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
  const projectName = projectNameDOM.value
  const projectDiscription = projectDiscriptionDOM.value
  const projectAuthor = projectAuthorDOM.value
  const projectCollaborator = projectCollaboratorDOM.value
  const projectTechnologyUsed = projectTechnologyUsedDOM.value

  try {
    await axios.post('/api/v1/projects',  {projectName, projectDiscription},{
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + userToken,
        },
      })
      showProject()
      projectNameDOM.value = ''
      projectDiscription.value = ''
      formAlertDOM.style.display = 'block'
    formAlertDOM.textContent = `success, project added`
    formAlertDOM.classList.add('text-success')
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    formAlertDOM.style.display = "block"
    formAlertDOM.innerHTML = `error, please try again`
  }
  setTimeout(() => {
    formAlertDOM.style.display = 'none'
    formAlertDOM.classList.remove('text-success')
  }, 3000)
})
```

I was expecting a 201 status code and a new project added in my database but didn't happened.

Comment: "HTTP 400" is not unauthernticated, you have messed up the parameters.

Comment: You haven't given your HTML, so debugging can't be done - but it's likely that either `projectName` or `projectDiscription` are invalid in some way.  Please edit your question so that it's a [mre]

Comment: https://github.com/rajeev-007-glitch/Minor/blob/main/backend%203/public/browser-app.js

This is the repo link maybe this would help and also updated the error mistakenly pasted another one.